# Combined Space and Time Phasor Diagram of a Synchronous machine

Tags: phasor, synchronous-motor

Consider a synchronous generator with its electrical and mechanical angles between them

In the left diagram δ is in mechanical domain but delta is also the electrical angle between Ef and Er in the right diagram.

If it was a 2 pole machine there would be no problem since mechanical angle=electrical angle

What if it was an n pole machine ? How would we impose a mechanical angle like in the left diagram to a combined Space and Time Phasor diagram ?

[image]

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. You just rotate it at higher speed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Induction motor electrical and mechanical angle](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/187835/induction-motor-electrical-and-mechanical-angle)

Comment: @Charles Cowie- I know about mechanical angle and electrical angles. I'm just curious that angle δ between Ff and Fr in the combined time and space phasor is in electrical or mechanical domain

Comment: The angle δ as presented in the phaser diagram is in the electrical domain. It would be determined mathematically in the electrical domain. It would only be represented in the mechanical domain to show the relationship with the structure of the machine. It could be "seen" mechanically using a stroboscope.