# Can anyone explain electrical and mechanical angle of BLDC motor?

Tags: motor, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, electromagnetism, brushless-dc-motor

If a 3 phase 6 pole BLDC motor is 120 degree trapezoidal/block commutated and 6 switching sequense is required.

How do you calculate the electrical degree per pole and mechanical degree?

How many electrical and mechanical rotations are there for 360 degree considering 6 switching sequense?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/187835/induction-motor-electrical-and-mechanical-angle